# What is the model for dist="logistic" in R survreg, and in what unit are the coefficients?

Tags: r, survival, accelerated-failure-time

Does anyone know the model and parameterization for surveg with dist="logistic"? I'm having trouble finding documentation anywhere. I checked Chapter 2.2 of Kalbfleisch and Prentice and only found documentation for log-logistic.

dist="logistic" appears to give coefficients in units of time, which is desirable for the project I'm working on where simple interpretability is important

Comment: The logistic link function is $Pr(y) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(\mathbf{BX})}}$. The coefficients can be interpreted as, e.g., "A 1-unit increase in $x$ results in a $\beta_x$ change in the log odds of $y$."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form of the model fit by `survreg()` is explained in Section 4 of the main [survival vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf). Its most general form is:

$$ g(y) = X' \beta + \sigma W$$

where the vector of covariate values is $X$ with corresponding regression coefficients $\beta$, $\sigma$ is a scale factor, $W$ is "any [probability] distribution that spans the real line," and $g()$ is "any monotone transformation of [outcome] $y$." Section 4.4 of the vignette goes into detail about how the software allows for a wide variety of distributions $W$ and transformations $g()$.

The term $X' \beta$ is the estimated $g(y)$ for the situation $W=0$, with the distribution $W$ (as scaled by $\sigma$) determining the estimated random variation about that value. The units of $X' \beta$ terms are thus related to the transformation $g()$. If it's a log transformation of a time outcome (as in an accelerated failure time model) then the units are in log(time). In that case you exponentiate $g(y)$ to return to units of time.

If you specify a "log-logistic" distribution, $g()$ is set to the log transform and $W$ is set to the standard logistic distribution. If you specify instead a "logistic" distribution, you still have $W$ as the standard logistic distribution but now $g()$ is just the identity--no transformation. The values of $X' \beta$ are directly in units of time.

You are welcome to try a non-log logistic model, but then (without the exponential back-transformation from the linear predictor in a log-logistic model) you will end up with the possibility of negative survival times $y$. Think about whether that makes sense for your application.